# Overload <<operator going into a polymorphic object

Tags: c++, polymorphism, operator-overloading

I have two classes, both of which have a number of classes extending them (for multiple levels). Because of the polymorphism, I only ever allocate them on the heap.

I would like to overload the `<<operator`, such that I can "stream" on into the other. I would like `A << B`, to be reduced to `A->setNext(B)`, where this function stores the B in an array - so I can do this five times and have all 5 in the array.

I would like to write the code for this in the 2 base classes and have the functionality inherited by there children classes. Is this possible?

Comment: "Because of the polymorphism, I only ever allocate them on the heap." Wuh..?  And not sure what the middle point means either.  As for the last point - assuming public inheritance, any non-private method in a base class can be called from a derived class.  Any public method in a base class can be called ON a derived class.

Comment: 2nd point - do you mean overload (repeated method name but with different arguments), or actually overRIDE (derived class inplementing a base class method)..?

Answer (score 0):

In the base class, you need somthing like:

```
class Base
{
    virtual void streamInto( Base const& other ) = 0;
public:
    Base& operator<<( Base const& other )
    {
        streamInto( other );
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Of course, this still leaves the semantic open: what do each of
the derived classes do with the `Base const&` they receive?  If
the behavior in `A` also depends on the type of `other`, you're
going to have to implement one of the classic double dispatch 
schemes.

And does `<<` really apply here?  If there's no formatting into
an external format, it's probably operator overload abuse.
Shifting, on something like a `BigInteger` class, would also be
acceptable, but that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

This might be something like what you're looking for.

```
// In B.hpp:
#include <memory>

class TypeB
  : public std::enable_shared_from_this<TypeB>
{
    //...
};

// In A.hpp:
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include "B.hpp"

class TypeA
{
public:
    TypeA& operator<<( TypeB& source );
    virtual void reset_B_list(); // (maybe)
    //...
private:
    typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<TypeB>> B_list_type;
protected:
    typedef B_list_type::const_iterator B_iter_type;
    B_iter_type B_list_begin() const;
    B_iter_type B_list_end() const;
    virtual void added_B( TypeB& new_source );
private:
    B_list_type m_B_list;
    //...
};

inline TypeA& TypeA::operator<<( TypeB& source ) {
    m_B_list.push_back( source.shared_from_this() );
    added_B( new_source );
    return *this;
}
```

Remember to replace any `new B(args)` expressions with `std::make_shared<B>(args)`.

If you can't use `std::shared_ptr`, almost exactly the same thing is in Boost.

I do agree with James that this might be an abuse of overloading, depending on what this all ends up doing.  Consider just using an ordinary function name like `setNext`, `streamInto`, etc.  If it returns `TypeA&`, you can still "chain" calls to it, like `A.streamInto(B1).streamInto(B2);` instead of `A << B1 << B2;`